# python unparsed data in response headers - requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a problem with response from webapp.

```
smth = requests.get('httpxxx')
```

then I get:

> requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError:
>   [MissingHeaderBodySeparatorDefect()], unparsed data: 'Compression
>   Index: 1\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Length:
>   291\r\nDate: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 15:03:05 GMT\r\n\r\n'

but some headers are parsable:

```
smth.headers
{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 01 Jun 2016 15:24:58 GMT'}
```

When contentlength is more than 1000 then response will be compressed, so destroy everything.

Comment: It looks like the data that's getting sent in that response doesn't have comma separation and instead separated by new lines `\r\n`. Could you post the raw header that you're seeing?

Comment: I suspect these '\r\n\r\n'.

Comment: Full header for this:
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 16:13:01 GMT

Compression Index: 1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 291
Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 16:13:01 GMT

The CR + LF is used for separating individual headers. It looks like server send two times headers in one response.

Comment: Could you post enough code for me to replicate your error?

Comment: I'm not able to. It's internal application, so you couldn't debug them. But all header I sended in last comment. 
Reply:
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 \nCache-Control: no-cache \nPragma: no-cache \nLast-Modified: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 16:13:01 GMT \n\nCompression Index: 1 \nContent-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 \nContent-Length: 291 \nDate: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 16:13:01 GMT